# QR Code image Size

Tags: qr-code

Is it possible to change the saving size of the generated code, i'm not sure is it a limitation due to the API that is running this.
This is the code a forum member gave to me.

```
    <html>
          <head>
             <title>Testing QR code</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function generateBarCode()
        {
            var nric = $('#text').val();
            var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
            $('#barcode').attr('src', url);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="text" type="text" 
        value="NRIC or Work Permit" style="Width:20%"
        onblur='generateBarCode();' /> 

  <img id='barcode' 
        src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=200x200" 
        alt="" 
        title="HELLO" 
        width="200" 
        height="200" />
</body>
```

I want it to be save at 200pixel  Width and Height but currently its giving me only 50pixel

[image]

Comment: Well if you took some time to read the code instead of copy/pasting it without further reflexion you would have noticed `size=50x50` ...

Comment: ops, yup i got it. i guess i notice the bottom one but not top,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the `size=50x50` on line 9 with the right size

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generating an image that is 50x50. Change the following line in your `generateBarCode()` function from:

```
var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
```

To:

```
var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=200x200';
```

(replacing `200x200` with whatever size you'd like the download to be.